# Open Activity From Another Module Giving Circular Dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, circular-dependency

I am working on Android app that has to call to Activity which lies in the Main Module. The Issue I am facing is, the Sub Module which contains a Fragment is unable to Access to Activity in the Main Module.
I have Just seen these links for the Help but the Problem of Accessing to main module activity could not resolved..

Here is the Fragment Class in the Module from where I am calling to Parent Module..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), QRScannedResultActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("sendedscannedcontent", resultString);
        startActivity(intent);
```

the Function Image from where I am Calling to main
[image: Image of Function error]

The Module Hirarchy looks like

[image: Hirarchy]

After Adding     `implementation project(path:':app')` in Gradle it Gives the Circular Dependency Error

[image: Circular Dependance Occurs]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName()` to get `QRScannedResultActivity` class reference

Assuming that `QRScannedResultActivity` is in `com.maximus.technologies.view` package, replace the package path if that's not the case

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
    Class.forName("com.maximus.technologies.views.QRScannedResultActivity"));
    intent.putExtra("sendedscannedcontent", resultString);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Exactly I have QRScannedResultActivity is in Main Module and I want to open this from Sub Module

Comment: this Code is not opening the Activity I want to Open

Comment: @UsmanAli did you check that the package path in `Class.forName` matches the package path of `QRScannedResultActivity`? Does this code opens another activity that is not the activity you want to open, or does it opens nothing?

Comment: It is Giving Circular Dependency Error

Comment: it Open Nothing Until I add implementation project(path:':app') in Another Module but after adding this It gives the Circular Dependance Error

Comment: when it opens nothing, does it give an error in the logcat?